# bootcode for arm cortex m0

Tags: arm

I am working on a ARM CORTEX M0 based microcontroller.

I have integrated the core with a ROM.
I have to now write a startup code/bootcode to check whether the core is able to bootup from the ROM.

Can someone help me in this?

Comment: What does "integrated the core with a ROM" even mean? Are you designing a new chip?

Comment: http://github.com/dwelch67  look at stmf0d is cortex-m0 specific, but I have many repositories that are cortex-m based which would all cover the issue of booting from rom.

Answer (score 0):

Usig CMSIS(Cortex Microcontroller Software Interfacing Standard) will make things easier if this is a choice: 
Implement the Imported Function SystemInit() to do whatever You want before calling main. 
The Function is called within the Reset_Handler() weak function once Restarting the Microcontroller.

; Reset Handler

Reset_Handler   PROC
                EXPORT  Reset_Handler             [WEAK]
                IMPORT  SystemInit
                IMPORT  __main
                LDR     R0, =SystemInit
                BLX     R0
                LDR     R0, =__main
                BX      R0
                ENDP